# How to remove a item on carousel of primefaces?

Tags: primefaces

I'm new on primefaces, i want to know: how to remove a item on carousel of primefaces if I click a button delete?

Thanks...

Comment: just remove the item from the list `myList.remove(item)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make @Daniel's answer into proper answer:

just remove the item from the list myList.remove(item)